# Bracketing seems to have no effect (Canon T6s)

Tags: shutter-speed, bracketing, aperture-priority

I am editing photos of the total solar eclipse 2019. I configured my Canon Rebel T6s to aperture priority and fixed ISO 100. I used bracketing +/-2/3. However, some pictures have identical shutter values (as recorded in the exif metadata accessed in RawTherapee).

For example
Pic1 = 1/15 shutter, 100 iso,  0.00 ECV 
Pic2 = 1/25 shutter, 100 iso, -0.67 ECV 
Pic3 = 1/25 shutter, 100 iso, +0.67 ECV (<-- should have slower shutter than 1/15)

How can pics 2 and 3 have the same shutter value yet have different ECV? What am I missing?

NOTE: some of my pictures did work as expected. Any idea why some did not?

Thanks!

Comment: What’s happening with the aperture settings?

Comment: @Xiota Generally (maybe always), when Canon cameras bracket exposure, all of the bracketed frames are based on a single meter reading before the first exposure. The exposure values for all of the bracketed frames are"locked in" at that time. That's why the *exposure lock* indicator is lit until the full sequence has been recorded.

Comment: What lens are you using? If a zoom, at what focal length?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and reading my question. I am using a telescope (f=1000mm) and a T-mount. So, the camera does not recognize the lens attached. Exif says FNumber=0.0 and ApertureValue=0.0.

Comment: Using the scope is fine (I do this regularly).  Also, when bracketing, the camera should not change the aperture (since that alters the depth of field).  It will normally bracket by changing exposure times.  I would have expected your 3rd pic to use 1/10th sec.  Not sure why the shutter time is the not longer.

Comment: @TimCampbell yeah. I too expected a shutter around 1/10th... BTW on a different set of images, I got the expected results [1/80, 1/125, 1/50]. Assuming my assertions are accurate, would you say that the camera messed up? I am an experienced amateur photographer, but I was borrowing a camera. So, I might not have adapted well to it.

Comment: It sure seems like it messed up.  Were you in 'continuous' shooting mode (aka burst) so the camera would take three bracketed shots in rapid succession with you just pressing the shutter button once?

BTW, for an eclipse, the solar corona needs quite a few stops of bracketing.  I used 13 bracketed shots when I did the Aug 2017 eclipse.  The camera can't natively do this.  I used software to control the camera (and timing of when it took each shot).

Comment: @TimCampbell Whoa! 13 bracketed shots. Did you combine them afterwards? Yes, I used continuous shooting mode. I think there was something screwy in the settings or how I was operating the camera. Seems like there is no "obvious" answer. So, I'm going to just count this a learning experience.

Comment: @AeroMac, yes - I did combine the exposures to produce HDR images.  The expert on eclipse photography is a guy named Fred Espenak.  He has a website called MrEclipse.com.  Fred is a retired NASA scientist but he is still the guy they use for eclipse predictions even to this day (nearly all eclipse prediction data in use is generated by him).  He is also an avid eclipse photographer and his website has loads of useful data.  He has also contributed to books on the topic (in particular, he wrote the eclipse chapter in the book "Lessons from the Masters").